# How to get data after colon in query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to this, so basically I'm still learning.

I have this query where I'd like to get the value after the `:`, however I don't want to hardcode it.
Assume that `1:True,2:False` is an id. In the future the id might increase, so if hardcoded as shown below, it'll cause me problems.

This is a basic query I've been working on:

```
SET @strSampleData = '1:True,2:False'

    BEGIN 

    -- this is what i hardcode it
        set @strSampleData = substring(@strSampleData,3,50)
```

What I know is that I need to break the `3` and `50` here, but I'm not sure into what.

Comment: Your string doesn't have a semicolon.

Comment: What *flavor* of SQL you use? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc. ?

Comment: sorry, but i just want to know if there's a way to break '1:True'

Comment: its sql server PM 77-1

Comment: the hints is find the location of , split it 1st, then find the location of :, chunk it

Comment: Jeff Moden's article on CSV splitting is insightful: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code
It gives output: 2:False

```
DECLARE @strSampleData AS VARCHAR(20)
SET @strSampleData = '1:True,2:False'
SET @strSampleData = substring(@strSampleData,CHARINDEX(',', @strSampleData)+1, 50)
PRINT @strSampleData
```

*Please mark as answer if answers this question*